# Does the total space of a bundle satisfy the Tietze extension property when the fiber and base space do satisfy this property?

Tags: gn.general-topology, fibre-bundles

We say that a Topological space $Y$ satisfies the Tietze extension propery, TE property,  if [in the formulation of Tietze extension theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) "$\mathbb{R}$" can be replaced by $Y$.

Obvioysly the product of two  TE spaces is again a TE space. But what about a twist product? More precisely assume that the fiber and base space of a fiber bundle satisfy TE property. Is the total space necessaryly a  TE space?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "$\mathbb{R}$ replaced by $Y$"? The usual name is an absolute extensor (for normal spaces), I believe.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes thank you. I revised it.

Comment: If $Y$ is a Polish space, then the answer affirmative (which can be proved applying the theory of absolute retracts).