# A retract algebraic subset of the plane which does not admit an algebraic retraction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gn.general-topology, real-algebraic-geometry

What is an example of an algebraic (=Zariski closed) subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is a topological retract of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but there is no algebraic retraction $P:\mathbb{R}^2 \to C$?

What is an example of such a situation in $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Comment: $y^2=x^3-x+1$ should work. There's no algebraic retraction because as an elliptic curve, it's not unirational.

Comment: What about $xy=0$?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger in fact the motivation for this question was this curve xy=0. I was thinking whether it is a [TE space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325708/does-the-total-space-of-a-bundle-satisfy-the-tietze-extension-property-when-the). Then i realized it is a retract of the plane hence a  TE space but I could not find an algebraic retraction. However i can not understand  your comment

Comment: and comment of @YCor

Comment: Yes $xy=0$ works, in the real or complex case, just using Zariski irreducibility (the image of the plane by a polynomial map should be Zariski-irreducible).

Comment: @YCor is it a consequence of Zariski connected? I guess.

Comment: No, $xy=0$ is Zariski-connected. Use irreducibility instead.